# UIPanGestureRecognizer velocity return 0 in Simulator Macbook M1

Tags: swift, apple-m1, uipangesturerecognizer

Currently, I am building an app that contains a feature that uses a UIPanGestureRecognizer. Previously, I used an Intel Mac, and the UIPanGestureRecognizer *velocity* attribute is working correctly and return the expected value. However, after I switch to MacBook M1, the velocity of panGesture always returns 0.

```
 @objc
func panGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    view.endEditing(true)
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view)

   // The velocity should have a value when a gesture is happening
   //.....
} // End of PanGesture
```

Is there any patch or some action to make it work properly, same as with the Intel chip? I would please appreciate some suggestions to fix the issue.

FYI: Testing the app on real device, and it still working fine.